# Can a Javascript function be called via wildcard?

Tags: javascript, variables, error-handling, wildcard

In Javascript, if a function is referenced that doesn't exist, I can catch the resulting error using:

```js
window.onerror = function(msg, src) {
  // insert logic here
  return true; 
}
```

By parsing the content of `msg`, I can determine what function the developer was trying to call, and then by creating a `Proxy` object, I can prepare the app to ingest the arguments passed to the non-existent function that was referenced should the same function be called again.

However, it'd be ideal if I could handle the reference the first time it occurs. I'm interested in knowing if there's a way to either capture the arguments in the error handler, or if it's possible to declare a "wildcard" function that could respond when an undefined function is referenced.

Does such a thing or methodology exist?

Thank you in advance for your consideration and time.

Comment: Shouldn't the developer who is making the function call know what functions exist?

Comment: interesting idea. No, there is no "wildcard" function to catch everything that 'blows'. even if you would catch the error and create proxy (or just define the function), the app could be in a very bad state - not a good idea to hide that. Are you dealing with your own/company code or arbitrary code?

Comment: Absolutely, but this is for a debugging tool. I'd like to request as little information out of the users as possible so that they can just test their code and get output.

Comment: I've called functions that don't exist before (typos or bad imports), but js telling me that the function doesn't exist is enough to correct my code. The arguments don't really matter to resolve that issue.

Comment: It's arbitrary code. The environment is effectively a browser object that receives JS injections to call functions with any number of arguments supplied by the user. Normally, the browser object is pointed at the user's code which responds appropriately to the injections, but when it's pointed at my tool, I'd like to dump the arguments into the DOM for diagnostics.